# /bin/sh - non interactive usage from Python

Tags: shell, python

I am invoking cmd from Python like this:

```
subpocess.Popen(['coffee'], shell=True)
```

which I belive is translated to:

```
/bin/sh -c "coffee"
```

From docs I have read that in non-interactive mode files like /etc/profile, /etc/bash.bashrc are not read and default $PATH is used (init $PATH). Am I wright? Is there the only way to add coffee to the $PATH is to copy it to /usr/local/bin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify the `PATH` environment variable in your Python script before starting the shell, i.e., some variant of:

```
import os

os.environ['PATH'] = '/some/new/path:%s' % os.environ['PATH']
subpocess.Popen(['coffee'], shell=True)
```

Note that setting `shell=True` is very often unnecessary, and you should be aware of the implications of doing so, especially if you are calling `Popen` using user-supplied data.  The general problem is that data containing shell metacharacters (e.g., ">", or ";", "&") and so forth can cause unexpected behavior.

*UPDATE*: For example, if I have a script called `/tmp/foo` and I want to run this using `subprocess.Popen`, this works just fine:

```
>>> import os, subprocess
>>> os.environ['PATH'] = '/tmp:%s' % os.environ['PATH']
>>> subprocess.Popen('foo', shell=False)
```

If I don't set `PATH`, then I get the expected error:

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Bad thing with shell=False is that it simply does not work (OSError: directory of file not found). I guess it requires absolute path.

Comment: You just need to set your `PATH` environment correctly, as discussed in my answer.  I've updated it with this exact example.